# server provisioning with Docker

Tags: docker, cloud, devops

I have little experience using chef for managing the DevOps. I was using AWS opsworks, there you can create a stack with layers and can configure it to create a new server instance for each layer or use existing instance. Now I'm trying to make my hands dirty with Docker. From my reading about Docker so far you have to spin off a new server instance, ssh to it and then run a Docker image on it. Is there a way I can create new server instances and install images on them using scripts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just concerned with playing around in a development environment, look at [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/), and [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). These are tools for orchestrating docker images and containers from your primary machine on a local VM running docker.

If you're interested in orchestrating containers and images with multiple servers on a production level, you will still need a configuration management tool like chef. However you will be doing less application environment setup in chef, just the basic docker configuration and container management.

If you aren't too attached to chef. I'd look at [ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/). It has some [configuration management modules](http://docs.ansible.com/docker_module.html) specifically for docker that are great for starting out.